# Is it safe to reuse a std container after std::move?

Tags: c++, c++11, std, move-semantics

If I have a `std::list`, for example, and I use `std::move()` to move its information into a `std::map`, is it safe to reuse the list by populating it with more data so that I can add more entries to the map? I vaguely remember being told by another programmer that `std::move()` puts things in an unknown state so you shouldn't reuse them after, but I would just like to confirm since I can't seem to find any information on this just by searching around.

If it's not safe, then would calling `clear()` on the list after moving it make it OK to reuse?

Here's an example of what I'm doing:

```
// Create the initial list, give it some data, then move it into the map.
typedef std::list<std::pair<string, uint16>> TListType;
TListType data;
data.push_back(std::make_pair("some string", 0));
data.push_back(std::make_pair("some other string", 0));

std::map<uint32, TListType> mappedData;
mappedData.insert(std::make_pair(0, std::move(data)));

// Insert more data into the list, then move into the map as a new entry.
data.push_back(std::make_pair("new strings", 9));
mappedData.insert(std::make_pair(1, std::move(data)));
```

The reason I have to do all this ugly mess is because I can't use initializer lists and I don't have Boost, so I'm a bit limited in how to initialize complicated data structures.

Comment: @AMostMajestuousCapybara: I think in this case the container isn't moved from, but rather its contents are moved from.

Comment: In which case the answer depends upon the type of the objects in the container.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After moving from the standard C++ library classes, they are in an unspecified state but otherwise entirely usable. The relevant section is 17.6.5.15 [lib.types.movedfrom]:

> Objects of types defined in the C++ standard library may be moved from (12.8). Move operations may be explicitly specified or implicitly generated. Unless otherwise specified, such moved-from objects shall be
>   placed in a valid but unspecified state.

None of the containers specifies otherwise (as far as I know).

From the sounds of it, you are actually moving the elements, though. However, for these apply rather similar restrictions based on the definition of what `MoveConstructible` and `MoveAssignable` means (from section 17.6.3.1 [utility.arg.requirements]; `rv` is the argument to either move constructino or move assignment):

> `rv`’s state is unspecified [ Note:`rv` must still meet the requirements of the library component that is using it. The operations listed in those requirements must work as specified whether `rv` has been moved from or not. —end note ]